# StartPartitionDataLossAsync throws FabricException

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to restore my SF service from itself on local 1 node cluster:

```
using (var client = new FabricClient())
{
    await client.TestManager.StartPartitionDataLossAsync(
        Guid.NewGuid(),
        PartitionSelector.PartitionIdOf(Context.ServiceName, Context.PartitionId),
        DataLossMode.FullDataLoss);
}
```

The call fails with `FabricException` with unknown error code:

```
System.Fabric.FabricException: An error occurred during this operation.  Please check the trace logs for more details. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071D0A
   at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeClient.IFabricTestManagementClient3.EndStartPartitionDataLoss(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.<>c__DisplayClassa.<WrapNativeAsyncInvoke>b__9(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
   at System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2`1.Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context, Boolean expectedCompletedSynchronously)
```

Trace log contains this error:

```
ProcessClientOperation for action 'ForwardMessage' encountered error FMFailoverUnitNotFound.
```

Answer (score 3):

Switch the local cluster to 5 node mode.

Single node cluster does not contain `fabric:/System/FaultAnalysisService` which is required for inducing faults.